# How to prove the inequality

Tags: probability

For an arbitrary characteristic function $\phi(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{itx}dx.$ 
Show that,
$1-Re$$\phi(2t)\leq4\big[1-Re\phi(t)\big]$ and deduce that 
$1-\big|\phi(2t)\big|^2\leq 4\bigg[1-\big|\phi(t)\big|^2\bigg]$

Comment: Is $f(x)$ real?

Comment: Yes real valued function.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given, I think that $f(x)$ is a pdf. Then we have: $$\phi(2t)= \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x) \exp^{2itx} dx =\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x) (\cos2tx+ i \sin 2tx) dx $$ so $$ 1- Re \phi(2t)= 1- \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x) \cos2tx dx =\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x)dx + \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x) \cos2tx dx $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} (1- \cos 2tx)f(x)  dx $$
but we have : $ 1- \cos 2tx = 1-\cos^2tx +\sin^2tx= 2 \sin^2tx= 2(1-\cos^2tx) =2(1+\cos tx)(1-\cos tx) \leq 2*2(1- \cos tx ) $. Hence, substitute in the above integral e get:
$$ 1- Re \phi (2t) \leq \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} 4(1- \cos tx )f(x)  dx = 4( \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x)  dx - \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} \cos tx f(x)  dx) = 4(1- Re \phi(t) ).$$

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be deduced from the the fact that $|\phi(t)|\leq 1$ since $\phi$ is a characteristic function, and the inequality $1-\cos(2t)\leq 4(1-\cos(t))$ (can you prove this inequality?)